# How to set a variable in Wordpress's $wp_query

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to use the `set()` function, to set `$wp_query->query_vars['paged']`.

What's the proper syntax for this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('name','value');
```